# Get specific words in a string

Tags: python, string, string-matching

I am fairly new to python. I have a this string

```
"DEALER: 'S up, Bubbless?
BUBBLES: Hey.
DEALER: Well, there you go.
JUNKIE: Well, what you got?
DEALER: I got some starters. "
```

I am trying to get all the words in uppercase that end with a colon. For example, I get DEALER, BUBBLES and JUNKIE from the string above. Thanks

This is what i tried. Seems to work. But not as accurate as I would want.

```
s = "DEALER: 'S up, Bubbless? BUBBLES: Hey. DEALER: Well, there you go. JUNKIE: Well, what you got?DEALER: I got some starters.";
#print l
print [ t for t in s.split() if t.endswith(':') ]
```

Comment: Welcome to Python, and to Stack Overflow! While many of us would be happy to help answer your question, we are much more likely to understand the problem and provide a helpful answer if you show us what you've already tried.

Comment: Especially since this looks vaguely like a homework problem....

Comment: as a hint look into regular expressions

Comment: my gut says it's not homework

Comment: Any more detail than "not as accurate as I would want"? Specific cases it's succeeding or failing on would be useful. Strings have `.isupper()` as well as `.endswith()`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i was thinking of using regular expression to make it better. I am not really familiar with it. I tried googling it, but the results i got wasn't of much help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to get rid of repeats. A nice way is with a set.

```
import re

mystring = """
DEALER: 'S up, Bubbless?
BUBBLES: Hey.
DEALER: Well, there you go.
JUNKIE: Well, what you got?
DEALER: I got some starters. """

p = re.compile('([A-Z]*):')
s = set(p.findall(mystring))

print s
```

This results in a unique set of names

```
set(['JUNKIE', 'DEALER', 'BUBBLES'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir @Graeme Stuart!! Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re 

regex = re.compile( "(?P<name>[A-Z]*:)[\s\w]*" ) 

actors = regex.findall(text)
```